# how can add log everytime the polling results in no detection of file. I want to add a log when polling results empty everytime

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

```
public class  SftpConfiguration {

public DefaultSftpSessionFactory sftpFactory() {
        
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory=new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
        factory.setHost("*******");
        factory.setPort(22);
        factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        factory.setUser("ishant");
        factory.setPassword("**********");
        return factory;
    }
@Bean(name="mydefaultsync")
    public SftpInboundFileSynchronizer synchronizer(){
        SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sync = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizer(sftpFactory());
        sync.setDeleteRemoteFiles(true);
        sync.setRemoteDirectory("C:/Users/ishant/Downloads");
        sync.setFilter(new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*.txt"));
        sync.setPreserveTimestamp(true);
        sync.

        return sync;
    }


    @Bean(name="sftpMessageSource")
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel="fileuploaded", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "5000"))
    public MessageSource<File> sftpMessageSource(){
        SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source =
                new SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(synchronizer());
        source.setLocalDirectory(new File("tmp/incoming"));
        source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
        source.setMaxFetchSize(1); 
        
        System.out.println(source);
        return source;
    }


    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "fileuploaded")
    public void handleIncomingFile(File file) throws IOException {
        log.info(String.format("handleIncomingFile BEGIN %s", file.getName()));
        String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "UTF-8");
        log.info(String.format("Content: %s", content));
        log.info(String.format("handleIncomingFile END %s", file.getName()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one in the framework but itself.

See `org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer`. It emits this log message:

```
        if (this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            this.logger.debug(transferred + " files transferred from '" + remoteDirectory + "'");
        }
```

So, every time when there is no files to transfer from remote dir, you'll see a message in your logs with `0`.

There is also another one in the `org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint`:

```
if (message == null) {
        this.logger.debug("Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'");
        return null;
    }
```

Which is emitted on a scheduled polling task when no new data to produce.

You also can look into a `ReceiveMessageAdvice` implementation for its `afterReceive()` method, when you just check for `null` on that `result` and emit a respective log message.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am new to this. Where should I implement this in my code.

Comment: IF you are talking about a `ReceiveMessageAdvice`, then see a poller's `advice-chain` option: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#smart-polling